# terraform template for loop create list of maps

Tags: for-loop, templates, terraform

I want to create a list for ip restrictions like

```
[
  {
    ip_address  = "185.46.212.12/32"
  },
  {
    ip_address  = "40.67.217.201/32"
  }
]
```

In my main.tf file I call

```
data "template_file" "foo" {
  template = "${file("${path.root}/ip_restriction.tpl")}"
  vars {
    lists = "${azurerm_app_service.app1.outbound_ip_addresses}"
  }
}
```

in ip_restriction.tpl

```
[
    list(
      %{ for listItem in "${split(",", lists)}"}
        map("ip_address", "${listItem}/32"),
      %{ endfor }
    )
]
```

when I use it in another ip_restriction it will not work. This is how I use it

```
ip_restriction =  "${data.template_file.foo.0.rendered}"
```

Is there a way to create a proper list with objects that contains dynamically ip address from a list which I can set to ip_restriction of another webapp.